# Use Bootstrap's justify-content-between and stack-to-horizontal col properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, frontend

I am designing a responsive form. My form has 1 label, 1 input field, and 5 buttons.

Both my buttons and the input field are under col-8.

**I want my buttons to be placed in such a way that:**

1. It should start placement below and at the beginning of the input field.
   (imagine 2 rows under a col-8)
2. Space between 2 buttons are equal.
3. On small screen, buttons will be shown as stack.

**Here are screenshots about what I want:**

[For normal screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf9GH.png)

[When small screens - it should be stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oPcE.png)

**Here is my code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container bg-dark col-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="id" class="col-4 col-form-label" style="color: white;">id</label>
          <div class="col-8">
            <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-4 form-group row justify-content-between">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">B</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">D</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">E</button>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-4 form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">B</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">D</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">E</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-4 form-group row justify-content-between">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">B</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">D</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">E</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried 3 times to place the 5 buttons.

1. first - only `row` and `justify-content-between`
2. then - `row` and `col`
3. finally - `row`, `col` and `justify-content-between`

But each of them either crosses the input field width (1st screenshot) or keeps gap from input field width (2nd screenshot).

How can I properly make the 5 buttons that satisfy both `justify-content-between` and stack [ `col` inside `row` ] properly?

A request: I would like to have a suggestion - that doesn't excessively involved using margin and padding, since this should be good in all screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup has a few problems. To avoid these in the future, read each dot (bullet point) under [How it works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works) section of the Bootstrap grid section.

Here's a breakdown of what was wrong:

- not all `.row`s were direct children of `.container` or `.col`. Because `.row` has negative margins, it needs a parent having horizontal *"gutter"* `padding`s to compensate the negative margins (or you could disable the gutter by applying `mx-0` or `no-gutters` classes).
- you applied `.offset-4` on `.row`, which is designed for `.col`s. This is important, because by applying it to the `.row` you misalign all columns in that row.
- to make use of `.justify-content-between` you don't necessarily need another level of `.row` + `.col`s. All you need is `display: flex` on the element, which can be applied with `d-flex` class.

As an alternative solution, I've changed last `.row` example to use a `.btn-group`, which is a slightly better UI solution for this type of action-bar layout. The custom CSS is mainly for switching it to vertical on mobile (which could also be achieve by applying `.btn-group-vertical` to it, but it doesn't sport responsive variants).
See it working:

```css
.custom-btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .custom-btn-group,
  .vertical-mobile {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .custom-btn-group:not(#_) .btn {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .custom-btn-group:not(#_) .btn:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .custom-btn-group:not(#_) .btn:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="bg-dark col-sm-6 py-3">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="id" class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-form-label text-white">id</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-8">
          <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col offset-sm-3 offset-md-4">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">B</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">D</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">E</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col offset-sm-3 offset-md-4">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between vertical-mobile">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">B</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">D</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">E</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col offset-sm-3 offset-md-4">
          <div class="btn-group custom-btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">B</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">D</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">E</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container bg-dark col-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="id" class="col-4 col-form-label" style="color: white;">id</label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-4 col-8">
          <div class="row justify-content-between" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;">
            <div class="col-auto" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;">
              <button name="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;">
              <button name="button" type="button" class="btn btn-success">B</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;">
              <button name="button" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">C</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;">
              <button name="button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">D</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;">
              <button name="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">E</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to mention some things that worked for me:

1. I had to make the `margin: 0%` and `padding: 0%` each time for `col-auto`, if I do not, then there is a gap created like in my screenshot.
2. I had to put each `button` in `col-auto` then each `col-auto` in `row`. Finally, I made the row `justify-content-between`, and of course, `margin: 0%` and `padding: 0%` for removing unnecessary gaps.
3. Finally I wrapped the whole thing under `offset-4 col-8` which was wrapped under `row`.

Comment: Units for `0` values in `margin` and `padding` are redundant. Correct forms are: `margin: 0` , `padding: 0`. I strongly advise the use of an IDE, as most decent ones will provide syntax hints out of the box, without the need of any extra configuration. Also, the use of inline styles should be avoided (they break responsiveness, as there's no technical way to use `@media` queries in inline styles).